# SNX's Staking rewards contract

Tags: solidity, staking, protocol, reward, synthetix

Could someone explain to me like I'm 5 the purpose of the `notifyRewardAmount()` function on the Synthetix's `StakingRewards` contract please?

I **think** it's connected to modifying the rewards campaign's finish time if there are still more rewards to distribute, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the purpose of the function in a clear way.

```js
function notifyRewardAmount(uint256 reward) external onlyRewardsDistribution updateReward(address(0)) {
        if (block.timestamp >= periodFinish) {
            rewardRate = reward.div(rewardsDuration);
        } else {
            uint256 remaining = periodFinish.sub(block.timestamp);
            uint256 leftover = remaining.mul(rewardRate);
            rewardRate = reward.add(leftover).div(rewardsDuration);
        }

        uint balance = rewardsToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(rewardRate <= balance.div(rewardsDuration), "Provided reward too high");

        lastUpdateTime = block.timestamp;
        periodFinish = block.timestamp.add(rewardsDuration);
        emit RewardAdded(reward);
    }
```

Full contract [here](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synthetix/blob/v2.97.3/contracts/StakingRewards.sol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The answer to this question can be found in this video in the minute 7:40 --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ-IRzCYSXI